# Python 2.X: Why Can't I Properly Handle Unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, pyqt4, python-2.x

I have been experimenting for a while with **Python 2.X** and unicode. But I've reached a point where it doesn't make sense.

**First problem:**

Some code will clearly explain what I mean. The txt variable is here to simulate the pyqt4 translate function. Which returns a QString.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtCore
txt = QtCore.QString(u'può essere / sarà / 日本語')
txtUnicode1 = unicode(txt, errors='replace')
txtUnicode2 = unicode(txt)
```

When print()-ing the two unicode strings, I get:

> pu� essere / sar� / ???
>
> può essere / sarà / 日本語

Surely I could get the same thing by using *QString.__str__()*, but my point is understanding, so for the sake of argument I would like to know:

- Why does the errors='replace' replaces all encoded characters when
  it's only supposed to be doing that in case of errors?
- Is there a problem with just using unicode(QString) to make the QString
  into a unicode string suitable for displaying?

---

**Second problem:**

I am trying to understand encoding/decoding.

```
>>> a = u'può essere / sarà / 日本'
>>> b = a.encode('utf-8')
>>> a
u'pu\xf2 essere / sar\xe0 / \u65e5\u672c'
>>> b
'pu\xc3\xb2 essere / sar\xc3\xa0 / \xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x9c\xac'
>>> print a
può essere / sarà / 日本
>>> print b
può essere / sarà / 日本
```

- Does print decodes a and b?
- Encoded-encoded UTF-8 is supposed to be
  decoded entirely? Shouldn't I have the encoded string printed?
- What is the difference between encoded and decoded unicode string?

Comment: Can you just clarify if you're using python 2.x or 3.x.  While it's (currently) obvious based on the u string prefix, it's important information for this question, and in the future the u prefix will be added back to python3 (pep414)

Comment: I saw a rehearsal for this [talk](http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spccy/http://lanyrd.com/2012/pycon/spccy/) recently. You should watch the video/slides of it once pycon is done.

Comment: @Daenyth: Cool, it's soon (March 10th 11:45 a.m. – 12:15 p.m.).

Comment: Unfortunately the console (Command Prompt) under Windows is a dead loss for testing Unicode I/O. It's a long story to detail all the brokennesses you will hit trying to `print` a Unicode string. It's not a Python-specific problem, but it makes experimentation with understanding Unicode a difficult proposition. You could practise on a Linux terminal or web interface that can do Unicode reliably.

Comment: I am using uxterm, sorry for people wanting to test my snippets on Windows, your best bet would be to dup stdout to a logfile and look at it with a proper viewer/editor. Also, I found this page very very useful and insightful: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: @Aki: The video is up now: http://pyvideo.org/video/948/pragmatic-unicode-or-how-do-i-stop-the-pain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's fire up the old standby, IDLE, and see if we can replicate what you're seeing.

```
IDLE 1.1.4      
>>> a = u'può essere / sarà / 日本'

Unsupported characters in input
>>> a = u'pu\xf2 essere / sar\xe0 / \u65e5\u672c'
>>> b = a.encode('utf-8')
>>> a
u'pu\xf2 essere / sar\xe0 / \u65e5\u672c'
>>> b
'pu\xc3\xb2 essere / sar\xc3\xa0 / \xe6\x97\xa5\xe6\x9c\xac'
>>> print a
può essere / sarà / 日本
>>> print b
puÃ² essere / sarÃ  / æ—¥æœ¬
```

Note that I see something different when I print `b`.  This is because my shell (IDLE) does not interpret a sequence of bytes as UTF-8 text, but rather uses my platform character encoding, cp1252.

Let's just double check this.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp1252'
```

Yup, that's why I get different behavior than you do.  Because your sys.stdout.encoding is UTF-8.  And that is why, despite `a` and `b` being completely different values, they display the same; your terminal interprets bytes as UTF-8.

So you might be wondering if we can convert our sequence of unicode characters `a` into a sequence of bytes that can be displayed in IDLE

```
>>> c = a.encode('cp1252') 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in -toplevel-
    c = a.encode('cp1252') #uses default encoding
  File "C:\Python24\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 18, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 20-21: character maps to <undefined>
```

The answer is no; [cp1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) does not support encoding Chinese characters as bytes.

Comment: So you could print a because python's print detects it's an UTF-8 string and converts it to cp1252? Whereas it just translates b as a cp1252 encoded string?

Comment: No, I can print `a` because `a` is a sequence of (16 bit) unicode characters.  But `b` is a sequence of *bytes*, and thus python needs to convert it to characters, and does so using the platform-default encoding, cp1252

Comment: My version of IDLE uses UTF-8. Unfortunately I can't duplicate the test either because it's applying some kind of encoding to the *input*.

Comment: @MarkRansom note that I cannot cut and paste the glyphs into IDLE, but I had to use an escaped version.  Look at my second (successful) assignment to `a`

Comment: This is very insightful, would you happen to know anything about my first 2 questions? I'm very interested in the details!

Comment: For me `sys.stdin.encoding` returns 'utf-8', and I'm sure I've pasted Unicode characters in the past, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Interestingly I can assign the pasted text to a regular (not Unicode) string and `decode` it into a proper Unicode string.

Comment: @ironchefpython: You have it backwards. When you use `print mystring` with a string of type `unicode`, python *implicitly* calls `mystring.encode(encoding)`, where `encoding` is either `sys.getdefualtencoding()` or `sys.stdout.encoding`, depending on the target. A console can only accept bytes (The `str` type), not the abstract concept of a sequence of codepoints (`unicode` type).

Comment: @Daenyth I clarified my answer to indicate I'm not using a console, but the IDLE shell, which is based on tkinter, which accepts both bytes and unicode strings.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly I suggest you read the excellent article by Joel Spolesky, [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). It's not about Python, but should help your understanding of what's going on.

The distinction between unicode strings and normal strings becomes much clearer in Python 3, but this is true in Python 2. A unicode string contains the unicode representation of a string, a normal string is a byte string containing an encoding of that unicode representation. The documentation for [unicode](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode) sort of explains what is happening. By passing in the `errors` parameter `unicode` is acting differently to when it's not passed and it is trying to decode the string. It's not clear what encoding it's trying to decode from, but it might think it's utf-8 when it's actually utf-16, or similar.

The `print` statement encodes the unicode string into whatever encoding your terminal is using. This maybe ascii, or it could be utf-8 or something else. `print a` is actually doing `print a.encode('utf-8')` behind the scenes.

I haven't answered all your questions, but the article I linked to should answer most of them. Hope this helps!